# Video support in Amarok

Tags: kubuntu, amarok

It seems that Amarok is supposed to have support for listening to Youtube videos as a music source:
http://amarok.kde.org/fr/node/502

I cannot find this feature in the "Configure Applets" button's popup (found in the lower-right corner of the Amarok window), nor in `Settings -> Configure Amarok -> Plugins`. Is this feature not available in the Kubuntu builds of Amarok?

This is on Kubuntu 12.10 with KDE 4.9.4 and Amarok 2.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Context view video applet**

http://amarok.kde.org/fr/node/502

> Submitted on Mai 28, 2008
>
> ...a video applet for Amarok 2, allowing you to view music videos
>   directly in Amarok's new context view.

http://amarok.kde.org/releases/2.6

> on August 13, 2012
>
> Since 2.5
>
> Remove context view video applet. Unmaintained and broken. (BR 242793)

http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=242793

> 2012-05-08
>
> Remove context view video applet
>
> Unmaintained and broken for quite some time.